# groovy .. passing closures as parameter to another closure

Tags: groovy, parameters, closures

By way of example ..

```
def data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def someFilter = {it-> it % 2 == 0}

def newData = data.findAll{it,someFilter ->
   someFilter(it)
}

newData
```

gives me an error  ..

The current scope already contains a variable of the name someFilter
   at line: 5, column: 27

is it possible to pass a closure (maybe anonomously) to another closure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass closures. I believe this is what you had intended:

```
def data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def someFilter = {it-> it % 2 == 0}

def newData = data.findAll someFilter 
newData // results in [2, 4, 6]
```

To pass a closure anonymously,

```
def newData = data.findAll { it % 2 == 0 }
```

The `it` variable is implicitly defined for the first argument passed to the closure; you only need to use the arrow syntax for multiple variables or for giving the first argument a different name, e.g.

```
def newData = data.findAll { nbr -> nbr % 2 == 0 }
```